# Resume a Flowable on TimeoutException in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a flowable setup like this

```
            getFlowable()
            .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                if(throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
                    view.hideLoading();
                    return Flowable.just(new WorkExperience());
                }

                return Flowable.error(throwable);
            })
            .subscribe(workExperience -> {
                // do something
            }, throwable -> {
                Timber.e(throwable);
                view.hideLoading();
            }));
```

Please note usage of `timeout` and `onErrorResumeNext` operator. What I am trying to here is continue receiving events from original flowable if there is a timeout after ignoring timeout exception. I am not sure if this is right approach because it doesn't seem to work. I am no more receiving events once timeout occurs. I can use some pointers here. Thanks!

Comment: I think `onExceptionResumeNext( )` is more suitable.

Comment: @CoXier but with onExceptionResumeNext how do I filter timeout exception?

Comment: @CoXier I tried `onExceptionResumeNext(Flowable.just(T))` and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep observing the source, don't timeout it. I assume what you really want is some alive notifications in every 5 seconds so that the user doesn't think the app froze. For this, just merge in a timer mapped to the "busy" value:

```java
getFlowable()
.mergeWith(Flowable.interval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(v -> new WorkExperience()))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(
    workExperience -> {
        // do something
    }, 
    throwable -> {
        Timber.e(throwable);
        view.hideLoading();
    }
);
```

Comment: So this flowable represents a data source, whenever a new element is added to data source an item is emitted. I am showing a loader upon first launch of screen, but since initially there is no data loader keeps on spinning. I have put timeout to takecare of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by moving the `timeout` operator and `onErrorResumeNext` inside another flowable:

```
private static Flowable<Integer> getFlowable() {
    return Flowable.range(1, 5)
        .concatMap(integer ->
            Flowable.just(integer)
                //the timer operator here is to simulate a long operation
                .concatMap(v -> Flowable.zip(Flowable.just(v), Flowable.timer(v, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (value, time) -> value))
                .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                    if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
                        return Flowable.just(-1);
                    }

                    return Flowable.error(throwable);
                }));
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    getFlowable()
        .subscribe(workExperience -> {
            System.out.println("value = " + workExperience);
        }, throwable -> {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }, () -> {
            latch.countDown();
        });

    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

```
        Flowable<WorkExperience> flowable = getFlowable();
        Flowable.just(1)
                .flatMap(i -> flowable)
                .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                    if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException) {
                        view.hideLoading();
                    }

                    return Flowable.empty();
                })
                .subscribe(i -> {
                }, Timber::e)

       flowable.subscribe(workExperience -> {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(workExperience.getCompany())) {
                    view.populateExperiences(workExperience);
                }
            }, throwable -> {
                Timber.e(throwable);
                view.hideLoading();
            })
```